# Unity + Facebook SDK: The name `FB' does not exist in the current context

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I want to integrate the facebook sdk in my existing unity game, but receive the following error message when trying to initialize the sdk: "The name `FB' does not exist in the current context"

I followed the "[Getting started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/gettingstarted)" guide as well as the "[Facebook SDK for Unity - Examples](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/examples)" part on the facebook developer page. Not sure what I'm missing and the docs aren't any help :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the Facebook namespace to your scripts referencing `FB`:

```
using Facebook.Unity;
```

Comment: I don't know what is wrong with me that I didn't see that, but thank you so much!